# How can I pass varargs to another function in vimscript?

Tags: vim, variadic-functions

I want to write a wrapper to a plugin's function, but it uses varargs (`...`). How can I pass the same arguments my function receives to the plugin's function?

Example:

```
function! PluginInterface(...)
    for i in a:000
        echo i
    endfor
endfunction

function! MyInterface(...)
    echo a:1 . ' is great'
    call PluginInterface(a:000)
endfunction

echo '>> Their call'
call PluginInterface('hello', 'world')
echo '>> My call'
call MyInterface('hello', 'world')
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of calling the function directly (`call PluginInterface(a:000)`), use `call()`:

```
call call("PluginInterface", a:000)
call call(function("PluginInterface"), a:000)
```

(That looks strange, but `call()` is a function so you still have to prefix it with `:call` or `let x =` or something that accept an `expr`.)

See `:help call()`.